# admincontroller using wrong helper for create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create an admin instance through my admins controller create action, but I keep getting an error that says:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AdminsController#show: Couldn't find User with id=4`

The trace indicates that it is attempting to use the sessions helper (for user) instead of the appropriate adminsessions helper.

```
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:20:in `current_user'
app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:12:in `signed_in?'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:13:in  
app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1013605049_93953830
```

I can log in correctly and the admin is created. I just think the problem has to do with the `redirect_to @admin` in my admins controller, though I'm not sure.

How do I set it up so that my admins controller uses the adminsessions helper instead of the sessions helper? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

adminsessions_controller.rb

```
class AdminsessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @title = "Log in"
  end

  def show
    @title = "Admin session"
  end  

  def create
    admin = Admin.authenticate(params[:adminsession][:email],
                               params[:adminsession][:password])
    if admin.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
      @title = "Log in"
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in admin
      redirect_to admin
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path                          
  end
end
```

admins_controller.rb

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @user = User.all
  end

  def show
    @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @admin = Admin.new
    @title = "New admin"
  end

  def create
     @admin = Admin.new(params[:admin])
    if @admin.save
      sign_in @admin
      flash[:success] = "Welcome admin!"
      redirect_to @admin
    else
      @title = "New admin"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

new.html.erb (form where I create new user)

```
<div id="signupform_new">
   <%= form_for(@admin) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :username %>
     <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "round"  %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :email %>
     <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "round" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "round"  %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
       <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "round"  %>
    </div>
    <div class="action">
      <%= button_tag "", :class => "acctSubmit" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    self.current_user = user
  end


  def signed_in?
   !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
   @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
   @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def current_user?(user)
   user == current_user
  end

 def authenticate
  deny_access unless signed_in?
 end    

 def sign_out
  session[:user_id] = nil
  self.current_user = nil
end

 def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
  clear_return_to
end

def deny_access
  store_location
  redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Please log in to access this page."
end

private

  def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.fullpath
  end

  def clear_return_to
    session[:return_to] = nil
  end
end
```

adminsessions_helper.rb

```
module AdminsessionsHelper


def sign_in(admin)
  adminsession[:admin_id] = admin.id
  self.current_admin = admin
end


def signed_in?
  !current_admin.nil?
end

def current_admin=(admin)
  @current_admin = admin
end

def current_admin
  @current_admin ||= Admin.find(adminsession[:admin_id]) if adminsession[:admin_id]
end

def current_admin?(admin)
  admin == current_admin
end

def authenticate
  deny_access unless signed_in?
end 

def sign_out
  adminsession[:admin_id] = nil
  self.current_admin = nil
end

def redirect_back_or(default)
  redirect_to(adminsession[:return_to] || default)
  clear_return_to
end

def deny_access
  store_location
 redirect_to login_path, :notice => "Please log in to access this page."
end

private

  def store_location
    adminsession[:return_to] = request.fullpath
  end

  def clear_return_to
    adminsession[:return_to] = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All helpers are (by default) mixed in and available in all controllers. Looks like the methods you are using should be protected or private members of your controllers instead. You can make them helper methods to be available in your views, i.e. `helper_method :signed_in?`.

Personally I never liked the lack of namespacing with helpers anyway. I like the presenter pattern much better (see [RailsCasts Pro](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch?view=comments)].

Comment: Thank you, aceofspades. Renaming the methods so that they are unique solved the issue. I shouldn't have assumed that each helper was specific to its controller.

Comment: If you're new to Rails @gemmy, again, these really should be protected/private controller methods. In Rails, there's a place for everything, learning Rails means learning where things belong. Glad this helped.